# Use \index before or after punctuation?

Tags: spacing, memoir, punctuation, indexing

It seems to me that you get different kerning if you use `say\index{say}.` than if you use `say.\index{say}` The following silly example is where I can see it:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
Some simple text about say.\index{say}
Additional text about say\index{say}.
say\index{say}. say.\index{say}
say\index{say}. say.\index{say}
say\index{say}. say.\index{say}
say\index{say}. say.\index{say}
say\index{say}. say.\index{say}
say\index{say}. say.\index{say}
say.\index{say} say.\index{say}
say\index{say}. say.\index{say}
say\index{say}. say.\index{say}
say\index{say}. say.\index{say}
say\index{say}. say.\index{say}
say\index{say}. say.\index{say}
say\index{say}. say.\index{say}
say\index{say}. say.\index{say}
say\index{say}. say.\index{say}
say\index{say}. say.\index{say}
say\index{say}. say.\index{say}
say\index{say}. say.\index{say}
say\index{say}. say.\index{say}
Can you see that there are lots of say\index{say}?
\end{document}
```

They look different to me:

[image: Sayings]

and so I ask, is the proper method `say.\index{say}`? Should any command come after punctuation (i.e., `\label` etc)?

Comment: `\index{say}say`

Comment: So if I were doing the shortcut that many recommend, would it be `\newcommand{\I}[1]{\index{#1}#1}` and would that kern correctly? I tested it with `\showoutput` and it seems to work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's easier to see the difference in the log file.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{microtype}
\begin{document}
\showoutput

1say.\index{say}

2say\index{say}.


\end{document}
```

shows

```
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 1
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 s
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 a
....\kern-0.32639
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 y
....\kern-0.97916
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 .
....\penalty 10000



....\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 2
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 s
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 a
....\kern-0.32639
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 y
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/12 .
....\penalty 10000
```

Which confirms, as you suggest in the question, that you lose the font-specified kern correcting the space before the `.` in this case `-0.97916pt`.

As I see egreg just commented it is best to put the `\index` *before* the word to avoid these problems.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I had seen something, and `\showoutput` may be useful. I wonder why none of the documentation recommend putting `\index` first.

Comment: @bombcar -- there are times when you would want to put the `\index` after, for example if you are indexing a multi-word string, like a name, the string might be split at a page break, and the word that is listed first in the index falls on the second page (Einstein, Albert).  then you should indeed put `\index` *after* the punctuation.  (i'm working on some index documentation, and, thanks to this question, i'll mention the kerning issue.)