# Put \index before or after a word?

Tags: indexing

Following https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167325, where it is suggested to put `\index` before the word, are there any other positive effects of saying `\index{word}word` as opposed to `word\index{word}`, apart from the right kerning in case a punctuation symbol follows? Does it make any difference when there is no punctuation around the \index{word}word in question?

Where does LaTeX allow (and where does it forbid) page breaks in

1. `\index{word}word`
2. `word\index{word}`

(note the beginning and trailing spaces)?

Comment: the main difference is that you potentially get a different page number if the word is hyphenated. In that case do you want the index to show the page with the start or page with the end of the word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

[image]

As shown in this example you can get different page numbers in the index if the start and end of the word are on different pages. There is no right answer here, you need to decide which output you want (and then work around any side effects on punctuation kerning that that choice has).

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}

aaa

\vspace{18.5cm}

zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz 
%\index{supercalifragilisticexpialidocious}supercalifragilisticexpialidocious
supercalifragilisticexpialidocious\index{supercalifragilisticexpialidocious}
zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz 
zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz 
zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz 
zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz 
zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz 
zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz 
zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz zzzzz 

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: @user49915 I'm not sure I understand your comment about majority, you just need to decide (most likely globally for the whole document) if a word splits over a page, which page do you want in the index. kerning can be addressed by eg `foo,\index{foo}` if needed because there is a kern between `o` and `,`

Comment: @user49915 no, there is no line or page breaking possibility there.